# Orange data mining 2.7 How to relate (not merge, not concatenate) 2 datasets

Tags: database, orange, relate

I am new using Orange using version 2.7  and I was wondering if someone can answer the following question: How to relate (not merge, not concatenate) 2 datasets in Orange? Thank you.
I have one table “Basic Data” with some general data:  caseId, age, gender, etc and a second table in which is stored  some characteristics in a field called “Conditions” that are many for each caseid. Both databases are related in one to many relationships where the caseid is the primary key.
So, my question is how can I relate both tables and then analyse data coming from both tables?  Can I do it with some Orange widget or do I need to build a code in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it in Python. There is no widget for this.

In Orange 3 you can store the data into Postgres and execute the SQL query in a widget. Orange 2 also has several alternative widgets for SQL but I guess they always remained just buggy prototypes.